# Using crypt_r on OS X

Tags: c, multithreading, gnu, crypt

I want to use the `crypt_r` function on Mac OS X 10.8.2

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <crypt.h>
```

produces

```
crypt.h: No such file or directory
```

Where can I get the crypt.h file from? Or am I including it wrong?

**Edited question - concrete example**

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    struct crypt_data * data = (struct crypt_data *) malloc(sizeof(struct crypt_data));
    char * testhash;
    testhash = crypt_r("string", "sa", data);
    free(data);
    return 0;
}
```

produces

```
gcc test.c -Wall
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:5: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct crypt_data’ 
test.c:7: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘crypt_r’
test.c:7: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

Comment: even with both I get the file not found error. --Edit: Answer to who ever deleted the comment: "#define _XOPEN_SOURCE is also required".

Comment: actually, not on OS X, sorry. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: `crypt_r()` is not available on OS X.

Original answer:

The contents of `<crypt.h>` on OS X is handled by `<unistd.h>`. So, instead of

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <crypt.h>
```

simply write

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

in order to access the `crypt()` function.

Comment: Then I get: `warning: implicit declaration of function ‘crypt_r’`

Comment: @kadrian You should not. What version of OS X and which compiler are you using?

Comment: gcc: `i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)` and Mac OS X 10.8.2 (should be up to date)

Comment: @kadrian for me, the same compiler and OS X 10.7.5 doesn't produce any warning.

Comment: @kadrian Sorry, overseen that. I wrote `crypt()` and not `crypt_r()`. `crypt_r()` is unavailable on OS X.

Comment: Ok, and no way to get it? Damn OS X! ;-)

Comment: @kadrian I think you can try compiling it from the GNU libc sources. (would you be as kind as to accept my answer?)