# Trouble linking crypt in c++ project

Tags: c++, c, encryption, crypt

I'm trying to use the `crypt()` method included in the [GNU C library crypt](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/crypt.html). I've looked at these similar questions, [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565427/c-crypt-function), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989444/problem-with-crypt-h-in-c), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127921/is-the-crypt-function-declared-in-unistd-h-or-crypt-h) but couldn't get any of the solutions offered to work.

I'm simply including these two things

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <crypt.h>
```

and the compiler is telling me

```
hashtable.h:7:19: error: crypt.h: No such file or directory
make: *** [pass.x] Error 1
```

How can I get the compiler to recognize crypt.h?

Comment: Are you working on OS X?

Comment: Followup: If you're working on OS X the crypt() function is declared in `<unistd.h>`. To my knowledge there is no `<crypt.h>` out of the box.

Comment: Yes, I'm working on OS X

Comment: Look here then:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14045543/using-crypt-r-on-os-x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have crypt installed on your system? If yes, find the directory with crypt.h and add it to compilers' headers search path: -I/path/to/crypt/headers

You wil also need to link to the crypt lib with -lcrypt , possibly telling the linker where the lib is with -L option.

Instruction on using crypt on OSX: [Using crypt_r on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14045543/using-crypt-r-on-os-x)